# Docker Distributed Application Bundle(DAB) no network creation options

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Before the new version of Docker i was using docker-compose with -H :swarm_manager_port to distribute my services. in the new version Docker introduced stack & bundle system to distribute apps,however i couldn't find any option to set a fixed ip and subnet to containers via an overlay network like compose and the classic swarm. in compose file,i declare a network with IPv4 & subnet options set.
so does anyone know how i can assign a constant ip (e.g.10.1.2.3) to containers via bundle and why bundle file does not support network options like "networks" in compose ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the moment it does not appear the creation of a network is part of the DAB file spec. It's still in development/experimental, so that might change, but [the README on DABs](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/29648795cd3709063c0f4309148708bbb5a3e7bc/experimental/docker-stacks-and-bundles.md) at the time of this answer states,

> Networks that the service containers should be connected to. An entity deploying a bundle should create networks as needed.